# compare time with symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I searched all over google but was not able to find a solution to my problem.
So i have this system where people are able to set tasks on a specific time.

When the time has already a task i should throw an error letting the person know
that the time is already reserved and that it won't be written to the database.
But for some reason im not able to accomplish this.

I think the problem has to do with the if statement

This is what i tried: http://pastebin.com/iA3RF6Mw

Many Thanks :)

Comment: To avoid that some broken link (in the future) makes this question almost useless for other users with this type of problem, you need to isolate and paste all related code directly inside the question

Answer (score 1):

[FIXED]

I made a new class whith a bunch of if else statements.

```
public function checkBooking($booking,$em){

    $reservations = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:Applicant")->findBy(array("date" => $booking->getDate(),"room" => $booking->getRoom()));
    $errors = 0;
    $bookingTimeStart = $booking->getTimeStart()->format('H:i');
    $bookingTimeEnd = $booking->getTimeEnd()->format('H:i');
    foreach($reservations as $reservation){
        $timeStart = $reservation->getTimeStart()->format('H:i');
        $timeEnd = $reservation->getTimeEnd()->format('H:i');

        if($bookingTimeStart >= $timeStart && $bookingTimeStart <= $timeEnd){
            $errors++;
        }
        if($bookingTimeEnd >= $timeStart && $bookingTimeEnd <= $timeEnd){
            $errors++;
        }
        if($bookingTimeStart <= $timeStart && $bookingTimeEnd >= $timeEnd){
            $errors++;
        }

    }
    $error = array();
    if($errors > 0){
        $error[] = "THis room is already occupied.";
    }
    if($bookingTimeEnd < $bookingTimeStart){
        $error[] = "The end time cant be bigger than the begin time.";
    }

    if(count($error) == 0){
        $em->persist($booking);
        $em->flush();
        return array();
    }else{
        return $error;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to catch whole logic but it is certainly wrong what you do:

```
 $time_start = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:book")->findByName($form->get("timeStart") -> getViewData());
```

You make lookup to "Name" by date fieled

And regarding how to check entity in date range, you should make your own repository method like

```
public function findInRange($timeStart, $timeEnd)
{
   $qb->select('b')
   ->from('Book','b')
   ->add('where', $qb->expr()->between(
            'b.date',
            ':from',
            ':to'
        )
    )
   ->setParameters(array('from' => $startDate, 'to' => $endDate));
  $query = $qb->getQuery();
  return $query->getResult();
}
```